# django models.ImageField not reusable

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a very simple ImageField class as follows:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',  height_field='width', width_field='height',
                              help_text = 'Please upload .png, .jpg and .jpeg extensions only')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

with the following form class:

```
class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Form for the image model"""
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('image', )
```

with the following template:

```
<div>                   
<form action='{% url "image-search" %}' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <p > {{ form.image}} </p>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
</div>
```

When nothing is selected, I see the page as follows, i.e. all normal behaviour:

[image]

But once I upload an image, the button just disappears and nothing is select able anymore. This is how it looks:

[image]

I am stuck here from quite some time, please guide.

Comment: You might have some CSS on input type file. Can you click that "1 FILE(S) SELECTED" and select another file?

Comment: This was exactly the reason. Many thanks for pointing out.